# Display Data based on Selected Item Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to display all orders in database based on selected option. 
The two options are Accepted and Declined. 
I have a an orders table with column "status"

On my view i am displaying all orders, this is ok. 
I want to also display data based on status at the top. 
Help is much appreciated.

My View:

```
<h1 class="text text-center">Orders Page</h1>

    <div class="panel panel-warning">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <p>Returning an array of all orders, filtered by status</p>
        <select>
            <option>Accepted</option>
            <option>Declined</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
         Display Data here
    </div>
</div>



@foreach ($orders as $order)
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel panel-heading">
                <p>Order Number: {{$order->id}} for retailerr: {{$order->retailerId}}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-body">
                <p>The Status of this order: @if ($order->status == '') <span style="color: red"> Pending approval </span>@else {{$order->status}} @endif</p>
                <p><a href="{{URL('orders/'.$order->id.'/edit')}}" class="btn btn-primary">Change Order Status</a>
                <a href="{{URL('orders/'.$order->id)}}" class="btn btn-success">View Order Details</a>
                {!! Form::open(array("method"=>"DELETE", "url"=>"orders/$order->id")) !!}
                            {!! Form::submit("Delete Order", array("class"=>"btn btn-danger")) !!}
                            {!! Form::close() !!}</p>
                <p>The total for this order: {{$order->total}}</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h5 class="text-center">Order by: {{$order->user->firstName}} {{$order->user->lastName}}</h5>
            </div>
        </div>
@endforeach
```

Controller Index Method:

```
public function index()
{
    //
    $data = Order::all();
    return view('orders.orderDashboard')->with("orders", $data);
}
```

Comment: May be you need to sort your data based on status

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = Order::all();
$finalArray = array();
$finalArray['Original'] = $data;
if(!empty($data)){
   foreach($data as $key=>$row){
     $finalArray['Sorted'][$row->status][]  = $row;
   }
}
return $finalArray;
```

Comment: some comments on your code above would be useful to understand what you are getting at